# LED not even turning on with avr

Tags: led, avr, atmel, avr-gcc

As the title states I have been having problems with programing my atmega328 to run a simple code that turns on an led the code is here

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define led_ddr DDRD
#define led_prt PORTD
#define led_pin PD6

int main (void) {

    led_ddr |= (1 << led_pin);
    led_prt |= (1 << led_pin); 


}
```

As you can very simple, the problem is eventhough i have everything connected in he right place with the avr programmer and the atmel chip it refuses to turn on the led.

The program i use is called atmel studio and it even doesnt recognize any problem nor does the programmer give any status led colour change it is just green.

the only thing i notice is that the led near the port side of the programmer starts blinking green not the status one.

I am wondring if it is faulty breadboard, chip or maybe something wrong with programmer it self or maybe even the code.

i am confused because i used to be able to program ctc interrupts now i cant even get an led to turn on.

Here is a schematic of my setup:

[image]

Comment: "i have everything connected in he right place". So how come it doesn't work? Last time I looked, the ATmega328 does not have a LED, so there's obviously lots of things you're not showing us.

Comment: Please add a schematic.

Comment: When I say led I am talking about the led that I connected to PD6

Comment: The LED is connected between PD6 and what?  What is the LED rated forward voltage, and the circuit Vcc.  Do you have current-limiting resistor in series with the LED? What value resistor?

Comment: well I just now added a link to a schematic, but in the case of the LED it is a typical 5mm led, the voltage of the whole circuit is 3.2V, and I figured that I didn't need a resistor for the led because, it works just fine off of the 3.2 volts when directly exposed to the voltage rails of the bread board, but it doesn't even light up when i put the led in series from PD6 to ground, that is why I am a bit confused.

Comment: You need a current limiting resistor on your LED. I'm not familiar with that chip so you may have blown the output by demanding excessive current.

Comment: Understandable I guess, I knew it was a bad practice to not use a current limiting resistor, but I thought  it didn't really matter in this case because I was just using it for a test. Plus I have done this many time before hand and never really had a problem. All though I guess I did do a lot of experiments with leds using that pin. However if it did blow out shouldn't the atmel studio program be able to pick up that something is wrong? Does a current limiter make that much of a difference when dealing with low voltages like 3 volts when the chip itself can handle 5.5 volts.

Comment: The programmer can't tell if you've fried an output transistor.  Use a 100Ohm resistor, and connect your LED to 3.3V and see it the LED is OK.  If so, try a different output pin - and use the series resistor.  If that works, then PD6 is toast.

Comment: dumb question but.. are you sure you soldered the LED in the right orientation? driving a pin high with a reverse biased LED will not turn it on.. maybe try using a blink program instead?

Comment: So an update is that I tried using an 1000 ohm resistor and it still doesn't work. I put the resistor in between PD6 and the positive of the LED and is still does not light up even though the led lights up when I connect it in series with a resistor to VCC. I also tried other different pins like PD4 and even a different port like PB1 and still no results. I made sure that the led is not reversed by constantly testing by hooking it up directly with VCC. It does not light up when I connect it to the pins of the microcontroller however.

Comment: Try `PORTD6` rather than `PD6`. Also, add `while(1);` at the end of main, just to make sure it is not resetting at the end of the main function. Also, please upload the .elf file produced during compile to somewhere so I can have a look.

Comment: I tried all that you said about making it PORTD6 and putting while(1); at the end of my main loop but to no avail, here is a link to my github folder that contains the .elf  https://github.com/AlviAhmed/Shift-Register-Sign/tree/master/GccApplication1/GccApplication1/Debug

Comment: I posted the answer below

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is not related to electronics design - the user simply used the wrong file when programming, not the one shown in the question. The question as it stands is thus obsolete and irrelevant to anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

In your schematic, the RESET pin of the ICSP header is connected to the positive supply; it should be connected to the other end of the 10k pullup resistor on pin 1.  This error will prevent the programmer from putting your chip into programming mode.  If it accurately reflects your setup, this alone will explain the behaviour you see.

Others' remarks about the need for a series resistor are also sound.

PS: Your schematic shows no supply decoupling.  It matters, you know.

Comment: oh it seems I made a small mistake in the schematic, I put the reset pin of the ISP behind the 10K resistor. I will fix my schematic immediately, btw if the programmer can't put the chip into programming mode wouldn't the atmel studio software alert me of that. Also about the decoupling, isn't that used  to smooth out ripples from voltage supply, but I use an atx power supply so assumed that decoupling was unnecessary since atx power supplies are used to power computer chips, I assumed it was by default that the atx had some sort of decoupling feature

Comment: You are right about the Atmel studio reporting whether it managed to program the chip.

But you are dead wrong about the purpose of supply decoupling capacitors.  They are to smooth out transients in the current drawn by your circuit; capacitors in the power supply can't do this for you, because they are at the wrong end of the supply leads, which may have significant inductance.  You may be able to get away without them, but if a circuit doesn't work then their absence creates an immediate suspicion.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer, and I am so sorry to say that it was a mix up with the files. As I was trying to post a link to Github for this particular project, I noticed that whenever I saved something, Github didn't receive my changes for that certain project.

When I looked into this matter I found that the file that I was saving and compiling (my main.c file) was actually saving to another project. I was actually modifying the C file that belongs to another project rather than the C file in the project that I currently opened.

I got confused because in Atmel studio it labelled the project as GccApplication1, and the file name was main.c, however the main.c file was the file of another project called avr_blinking_test (since I name all my c files main.c, just project name is different).

That was what I was modifying but what I was actually compiling and sending to the chip was the main.c file from the GccApplication1 which, coincidentally enough was a blank program which explained the lack of blinking or lighting up from the LED.

This was a problem for me for almost a week until I noticed the issue with Github just now.

I would like to apologize for wasting all of your time, I learned a lot from all of you and thank you very much for all of your help